# Windows 8 Pro on MacBook Pro 15" early 2011. Multitouch and reversed scroll?

Tags: macbook-pro, windows, multi-touch

I've installed the newly released Windows 8 Pro on my MacBook Pro, and I'd love to get multi-touch gestures working such as pinch to zoom and 3 finger middle click tapping. I'd also like to reverse the scrolling so that it's like Mountain Lion.

Has anyone got any ideas of what would work, or what was great in Windows 7 so that I could try?

I used one under Windows 7, I think it was trackpad++ or something, but I found this to be a bit flaky, and it used to require updates which broke it and required re-installing. I'd rather avoid that if possible.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you remove OS X?

Answer (score 1):

For the reverse scrolling I use "[X-Mouse Button Control](http://www.highrez.co.uk/downloads/XMouseButtonControl.htm)".

I'm also searching for a way to implement the other gestures, but have been unable to find anything satisfactory as of writing.